# Count Number of Rows with Condition

Tags: powershell

I have a document names.csv with two columns. I want to count the number of rows that have the same values and modify the document to display the count using Powershell. For example:

```
Joe     Florida
Joe     California
Joe     Florida 
Bob     Texas
Joe     Texas
Joe     Florida
Joe     Florida
Bob     Minnesota
Joe     California
```

I want the output to be:

```
Bob     Minnesota     1
Bob     Texas     1
Joe     California     2
Joe     Florida     4
Joe     Texas     1
```

This needs to be generic because column 1 will contain an arbitrary number of names. I really do not know where to begin. Please only answer with full names (do not say `gc` for `Get-Content`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet here like below.

If csv is like below

```
Name,Place
Joe,Florida
Joe,California
Joe,Florida,
Bob,Texas
Joe,Texas
Joe,Florida
Joe,Florida
Bob,Minnesota
Joe,California



Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Temp.csv | Group-Object -Property Name,Place
```

You can put your own logic to write it to new csv.

Comment: I suggest: `Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Temp.csv | Group-Object -Property Name,Place -NoElement`